# Segmentation fault : Cannot access memory

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, mergesort

I am implementing merge sort code. The code I have written is :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void merge(int *A,int i,int k,int j)
{
    int l1,l2,c,d;
    int B[j - i + 1],ind = 0;
    l1 = k - i + 1; c = i;
    l2 = j - k; d = k + 1;

    while(l1 > 0 && l2 > 0)
    {
        if(A[c] < A[d])
        {
            B[ind] = A[c];
            c++; l1--;
        }
        else
        {
            B[ind] = A[d];
            d++; l2--;
        }
        ind++;
    }
    while(l1 != 0)
    {
        B[ind] = A[c];
        c++; l1--; ind++;
    }
    while(l2 != 0)
    {
        B[ind] = A[d];
        d++; l2--; ind++;
    }
    for(int l = i;l < j - i + 1;l++)
    {
        A[l] = B[l];
    }
}
int mergesort(int *A,int i,int j)
{
    if(i == j)
        return 0;
    int k = (j - i)/2;
    mergesort(A,i,k);
    mergesort(A,k + 1,j);
    merge(A,i,k,j);
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    int A[] = {1,5,3,4,2,6};
    mergesort(A,0,5);
    for(int i = 0;i < 6;i++)
    {
        cout<<A[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

The compiler is giving the following error :

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000008000b34 in mergesort (A=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 
0x7fffff7eeff8>,
i=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffff7eeff4>,
j=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffff7eeff0>) at inv_count.cpp:42
42      {
```

If only first instance of mergesort is called the program is running fine. But it's giving error for the second call.
Can someone tell me why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation of midpoint k is wrong it should be :

```
int k=(i+j)/2 ;
```

this resolves the segmentation fault error but the merge logic is also incorrect.